# Been hit by a spell cast during a TimeStop while I'm invisible?

Tags: firetop-mountain

Is it possible to be hit by a spell cast by a mage who is in a TimeStop turn, while my mage is currently invisible? Is this a bug or is it actually foreseen by the rules of the game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is absolutely possible, no bug.
The rules ( see [here](http://www.gamerz.net/~fm/Main/index.html)) may not seem super crystal clear, but after it happened to me to be the target of a spell while I was invisilble and the opponent used time stop, I asked clarifications to the game "janitors" and it is applied as intended (no bug).

During a Time Stop your opponent is not covered by any enchantment or other spells as you hit from a parallel time line.

However, I don't know what would happen if both mages cast a time stop on the same turn.

Comment: The first time I got hit by a Time Stopped Anti Spell while I was invisible I was really, really surprised...

Comment: It's even funnier Time Stopping your giant while your opponent is under Protection or invisibility...